# How to read a file with 4 images in it, then separate those and send to local directory

Tags: java

The following Java program is code to read 4 image files, then save them together as ZappedJpgFiles.dat (may not be completely correct code).

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class ReadingFiles { 
   private static byte[] readBytesFromFile(String filePath) {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
        byte[] bytesArray = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(filePath);
            bytesArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            //read file into bytes[]
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            fileInputStream.read(bytesArray);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fileInputStream != null) {
                try {
                    fileInputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return bytesArray;
    }
public static void main(String args[]) {
        int numfiles = 4; //sets number of files as 4
        //JpgFile[] jpgfiles = new JpgFile[numfiles];
        String[] JpgFileLocations = { "src\\images\\Picture1.jpg", "src\\images\\Picture2.jpg", 
                "src\\images\\Picture3.jpg", "src\\images\\Picture4.jpg" }; // defines the locations of where all the pictures are
        FileOutputStream fout = null; // fout set to zero
        try {
            fout = new FileOutputStream("ZappedJpgFiles.dat"); // fout goes to zapped.dat
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // if the file does exist but for some reason is inaccessible,
            // for example when an attempt is made to open a read-only file for writing.
            System.out.println("ZappedJpgFiles.data cannot be written. Error - " + e.getMessage());
        }
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null; //oos set to null
        try {
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout); //zapped.dat is the new oos
            oos.writeInt(numfiles); //writes the number of files 4
            for (int i = 0; i < numfiles; i++) { // for every file, write the string PictureX.jpg
                oos.writeUTF("Picture" + i + ".jpg");
                // convert the file to byte[]

                byte[] bFile = readBytesFromFile(JpgFileLocations[i]); //reads bytes from whatever picture
                oos.writeInt(bFile.length); // writes the integer of how many bytes 
                oos.write(bFile); //finds array of bytes of picture then writes it to oos
            }
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
            System.out.println("successfully written file to data ZappedJpgFiles.dat");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException. Error - " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is that I need to come up with a code that basically does the opposite of this code, where I read the file ZappedJpgFiles.dat that I have in my files, then split it into the 4 image files and save them to my local directory. Not unzipping, just separating them. I believe I can split them based on bytesArray and using the read function() but not sure how... I also believe my ReadingFiles class stays the same, and I use the readBytesFromFile function in my main class, but not sure how my main class is supposed to look. Any help would be appreciated.

***EDIT:***
I've kept the ReadingFiles class the same, and now my main class looks like this so far:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    int numfiles = 4;
    String[] JpgFileLocations = { 
        "C:/file/to/path/WhereSeparatedGoes/Picture1.jpg", 
        "C:/file/to/path/WhereSeparatedGoes/Picture2.jpg", 
        "C:/file/to/path/WhereSeparatedGoes/Picture3.jpg", 
        "C:/file/to/path/WhereSeparatedGoes/Picture4.jpg"
    };

    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:/file/to/path/ZappedJpgFiles.dat")); //retrieving Zapped file... making a new ois
    System.out.println("" + ois.readInt()); // reads the first int, which is the number of files
    for (int i = 0; i < numfiles; i++) { // makes a loop to go through each picture
        ois.readUTF(); //reads the title (strings) of each image
        byte[] bFile = readBytesFromFile(JpgFileLocations[i]); //reading the bytes from corresponding picture... not sure if I should instead read bytes from the .dat file?
        System.out.println("" + ois.readInt()); // reads the integer of how many bytes 
        ois.read(bFile); //reads array of bytes then write it to ois

        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(JpgFileLocations[i])); // for sending info to JpgFileLocations[i]
        oos.write(); // the portion where I write the information of the pictures to the corresponding ones, but not sure how to do this??

        }        
    ois.close(); // not sure if this bottom portion is right as well, if i need to flush and also need to close oos?
    System.out.println("Successfully split the file into the four jpg files and saved to local directory");
    }
}
```

I've added comments to show what I'm doing... I'm mostly having trouble now with writing to the picture files to make sure they have the correct data after the ObjectOutputStream, and saving them to my "WhereSeparatedGoes" directory. I'm not very efficient at implementing Serializable, please excuse any mistakes! How may this class be corrected?

Comment: This is Java serialization. Open the file with an ObjectInputStream, then reverse everything you do to `oos`: read in the numFiles, then in a loop read in a UTF string for each image (as name / title?), then the count of bytes then read in that number of bytes.

Comment: @Rup Thank you for clarifying! That makes sense. I went ahead and edited the question with what code I have so far based on that, but still having some trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the fixed version. Points to note:

- You ought not really hard-code the number of images or the number of output filenames: you're going to read that from the serialized file. Instead I store a target path for the output and generate the filenames based on that.
- Why are you still calling readBytesFromFile()? That's still reading in the original file. Instead you want to use the number of bytes you've just read from the serialized file to make a new empty bytes buffer to read the file into.
- Reading the file in is a bit tricky since .read() doesn't guarantee it gives you as much data as you asked for in one go here, so I had to add a loop for this. This looks like readBytesFromFile so you might want to extract it into a new function like that.
- Writing out the file with OutputObjectStream is wrong: you'll end up with a JPEG wrapped in a Java serialization file. Just use FileOutputStream, similar to how readBytesFromFile worked.
- You don't need to comment every line of code. Once you get used to reading Java it's easier to read and write higher level comments. But do whatever's useful for you.

and the code:

```
public class WritingFiles {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        String jpgFileLocation = "C:/file/to/path/WhereSeparatedGoes/";

        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:/file/to/path/ZappedJpgFiles.dat"));
        int numfiles = ois.readInt();
        System.out.println("" + numfiles);

        for (int i = 0; i < numfiles; i++) {
            // Read in the header information for the stored image: title and number of bytes
            String title = ois.readUTF();
            int length = ois.readInt();
            System.out.println(title + " " + length);

            // Read in the image into a new buffer. We can't guarantee .read() will return us the full image in
            // one go, so we need to loop until we have all the bytes we expect.
            byte[] bFile = new byte[length];

            int cursor = 0;
            while (cursor < length) {
                int bytesRead = ois.read(bFile, cursor, length - cursor);
                if (bytesRead < 0) {
                    throw new IOException("EOF reading " + title);
                }
                if (bytesRead == 0) {
                    throw new IOException("Failed to read bytes for " + title);
                }
                cursor += bytesRead;
            }

            // Write out the image. Generate a filename based on the path and the loop number.
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
            try {
                fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(jpgFileLocation + String.format("Picture%d.jpg", i + 1));
                fileOutputStream.write(bFile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (fileOutputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        fileOutputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ois.close();
        System.out.println("Successfully split the file into the four jpg files and saved to local directory");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help, this is very appreciated. I tried using your code. My questions are 1) Since you took out readBytesFromFile, does this mean I don't need my ReadingFiles class anymore since it's never used locally then? Just this WritingFiles class? ... and 2) After only having the WritingFiles class, I get a warning that says "Resource leak: 'ois' is never closed. I see though that you did put ois.close() near the end of the code. Is it supposed to be placed somewhere else? It looks correct to me as I don't believe it'd be in the for loop so not sure why it says that.

Comment: 3) After testing the code with just the WritingFiles class, I did see output in the terminal (number of files, each picture title and their bytes, and the "Successfully split" statement) so it seems like it's calculating the right things. However when I go into my local directory WhereSeparatedGoes, the folder is empty. Is this just because there was something wrong with the ois.close(); or is that another issue?

Comment: Sorry, realized it only went to my parent directory of WhereSeparatedGoes, and I just had to add a '/' at the end of the jpgFileLocation path. I also went ahead and took out the ReadingFiles class, and it all runs now just fine. :) Still not sure about ois.close()'s warning however?

Comment: 1) No, you just need this code to split the Zapped file up. Although this code is more or less a copy of all of that code with a few modifications. 2) I don't get that warning, but it might want a try-finally block: ois wouldn't be closed if an exception was thrown. Try putting everything between the `ObjectInputStream ois = ...` line and the `ois.close()` line in a `try { ... }` block, and put `ois.close()` in a `finally { ... }` block [like this](https://gist.github.com/RupW/521364b242f37be1d5597cba022ad15b).

Comment: Thank you so much! The try-finally block makes the warning go away and it works perfectly. I really appreciate all the help!!